# How to switch to and from in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

I am trying to navigate to iframe and come back to top frame using selenium.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="testID">This is upper frame</div>
        <iframe src="test.html"></iframe>
     </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the testID which I am getting easily using `driver.findElement(By.id("testID"))`.

And then I want to navigate to iframe using `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("new_page")));` 
where `new_page` is the id inside `test.htm`.

Now, my requirement is to switch back so that I can again read `testID` from the above body.

But if I use:
`driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("testID")));`
I am getting exception like:

> unable to locate element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To switch to frame :**

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

**To switch to main window back :**

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Also I suggest to find element of frame first do switch and then find element.

You can switch to frame by following 3 ways :

> By Frame Index
>
> By Frame ID or Name
>
> By Frame WebElement

For More Details Please check : [Switch to Frame in Selenium](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/interact-with-elements-inside-an-iframe/)

I hope it help you..